# How to make a tool/package available via apt-get install x for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package, publish

Swift lang, for example, isn't available as `apt-get -y install swift` or any variant of name. I had to install it on the 24.04 ubuntu in Docker like this:

```
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install binutils
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install git
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install unzip
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install gnupg2
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install libc6-dev
# RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install libedit2
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install libgcc-11-dev
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install libpython3-dev
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install libsqlite3-0
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install libstdc++-11-dev
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install libxml2-dev
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install libz3-dev
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install pkg-config
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install python3-lldb
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install tzdata
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && apt-get -q -y install zlib1g-dev
RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install swift
ARG SWIFT_SIGNING_KEY=A62AE125BBBFBB96A6E042EC925CC1CCED3D1561
ARG SWIFT_PLATFORM=ubuntu22.04
ARG SWIFT_BRANCH=swift-5.9.2-release
ARG SWIFT_VERSION=swift-5.9.2-RELEASE
ARG SWIFT_WEBROOT=https://download.swift.org

ENV SWIFT_SIGNING_KEY=$SWIFT_SIGNING_KEY \
    SWIFT_PLATFORM=$SWIFT_PLATFORM \
    SWIFT_BRANCH=$SWIFT_BRANCH \
    SWIFT_VERSION=$SWIFT_VERSION \
    SWIFT_WEBROOT=$SWIFT_WEBROOT

RUN set -e; \
    ARCH_NAME="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"; \
    url=; \
    case "${ARCH_NAME##*-}" in \
        'amd64') \
            OS_ARCH_SUFFIX=''; \
            ;; \
        'arm64') \
            OS_ARCH_SUFFIX='-aarch64'; \
            ;; \
        *) echo >&2 "error: unsupported architecture: '$ARCH_NAME'"; exit 1 ;; \
    esac; \
    SWIFT_WEBDIR="$SWIFT_WEBROOT/$SWIFT_BRANCH/$(echo $SWIFT_PLATFORM | tr -d .)$OS_ARCH_SUFFIX" \
    && SWIFT_BIN_URL="$SWIFT_WEBDIR/$SWIFT_VERSION/$SWIFT_VERSION-$SWIFT_PLATFORM$OS_ARCH_SUFFIX.tar.gz" \
    && SWIFT_SIG_URL="$SWIFT_BIN_URL.sig" \
    # - Grab curl here so we cache better up above
    && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -q update && apt-get -q install -y curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    # - Download the GPG keys, Swift toolchain, and toolchain signature, and verify.
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && curl -fsSL "$SWIFT_BIN_URL" -o swift.tar.gz "$SWIFT_SIG_URL" -o swift.tar.gz.sig \
    && gpg --batch --quiet --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$SWIFT_SIGNING_KEY" \
    && gpg --batch --verify swift.tar.gz.sig swift.tar.gz \
    # - Unpack the toolchain, set libs permissions, and clean up.
    && tar -xzf swift.tar.gz --directory / --strip-components=1 \
    && chmod -R o+r /usr/lib/swift \
    && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" swift.tar.gz.sig swift.tar.gz \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl
```

It works fine. Is there a way to publish it to the ubuntu package system so it works like `apt-get -y install swiftlang` or somethiing like that `apt-get install myswiftlang`?

Wondering in general how to publish packages to ubuntu package system, and using this swift case as one small specific example.

P.S. if it's not allowed/recommended to do this, why not? In that case, wondering why it's not as easy to publish a package as Node.js's npm.

Comment: Not sure how this needs more focus, I am just asking how to publish an ubuntu package to use with `apt-get install`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. The simple solution is to create a PPA for publishing your own packages.

Comment: You do know `apt-get install` allows you to pass a _list_ of packages to install on its command line?